# Opening a csv file from an API with python

Tags: python, csv, asp.net-web-api, awr

So I am trying to download a file from and API which will be in csv format

I generate a link with user inputs and store it in a variable exportLink

```
import requests
#getProjectName
projectName = raw_input('ProjectName')
#getApiToken
apiToken = "mytokenishere"
#getStartDate
startDate = raw_input('Start Date')
#getStopDate
stopDate = raw_input('Stop Date')

url = "https://api.awrcloud.com/get.php?action=export_ranking&project=%s&token=%s&startDate=%s&stopDate=%s" % (projectName,apiToken,startDate,stopDate)
exportLink = requests.get(url).content
```

- exportLink will store the generated link
- which I must then call to download the csv file using another
  requests.get() command on exportLink
- When I click the link it opens the download in a browser,
- is there any way to automate this so it opens the zip and I can begin
  to edit the csv using python i.e removing some stuff?

Comment: Could you provide an example of such link?

Comment: Example Response:
    ok
    https://api.awrcloud.com/get.php?action=get_export&token=myAPItoken&project=project+name&fileName=2013-07-23-2013-12-27

Answer (score 0):

If you have bytes object `zipdata` that you got with `requests.get(url).content`, you can extract file by file to another bytes object

```
import zipfile
import io
import csv

with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(zipdata)) as z:
    for f in z.filelist:
        csvdata = z.read(f)
```

and then do something with `csvdata`

```
reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(csvdata.decode()))
...
```